# Retrieve last mongodb entry in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I Need help to retrieve last record from my collection. I have this code:

```
    db.collection('bbb1collection', function(err, collection) {
    collection.find({}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1).toArray(function(err, results) {
        path = results;
    console.log(results);
}
```

Comment: What does your console.log show?  You should put your code in the question rather than in the image.

Comment: Please do not reference code in images. It makes it troublesome to edit your work...

Comment: sorry was asking my first question. The console doesn't show anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this:

```
db.collection('bbb1collection', function(err, collection) {
  collection
    .find()
    .sort({$natural: -1})
    .limit(1)
    .next()
    .then(
      function(doc) {
        console.log(doc);
      },
      function(err) {
        console.log('Error:', err);
      }
    );
});
```

read about `$natural` [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/)

Answer (score 5):

Use this query:

```
db.users.find().limit(1).sort({$natural:-1})
```

Comment: I am very new at this. Can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: sure. As each mongo objects have _id which is usually a value based on timestamp so it is always sorted in asc order latest one at top. So we just sort it reverse by specifying -1 in $natural operator which tells mongo to use _id field for sorting. Also for readability you can place limit at last doesn't matter ordering or performance issue either. 
so it is same as db.users.find().sort({_id: - 1}).limit(1);

Answer (score 0):

```js
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { db.get().collection('bbb1collection').find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1).next().then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    resolve(res)
});
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.